# Upload Image through API in CKEditor 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor4.x

I'm using Ckeditor 4 to upload image. I want to send image to api and output will be a image url. Here is my ckeditor:

HTML:

```
<textarea cols="80" rows="10" id="ckeditor1" name="ckeditor1" data-sample-short></textarea>
```

JS:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('ckeditor1', {
  height: 300,
  filebrowserImageUploadUrl: 'https://example.com/api/image/editor',
  filebrowserUploadMethod: 'form',             
  fileTools_requestHeaders: {
       'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
       'access-token': 'token' 
  }
});
```

At the end. It alert 'Image Source URL Is Missing'. Because my API return:

```
{image_url: "https://exmaple.com/image/image.png"}
```

Is there any way that I can handle this object, and add image to ckeditor ?

Comment: Hello @Jon, do you have an example of the error you are getting? Or what should appear and what appears instead.

Comment: Hi @MihailMinkov, After I uploaded. It returned an object. You can see the object in my post.  But it's a wrong way because ckeditor cannot handle this object. I need to handle this object so that I can add it to my ckeditor at the end.

Comment: Do you have the function which processes your file input server-side?

Comment: Also, have you checked in the network tab of developer tools what does the server-side image processing function receive as data?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to estimate what you need in this case.

From what I can see you were using [this example](https://makitweb.com/custom-file-upload-in-ckeditor-with-php/).

Basically what you have in this case are three steps:

1. You use the upload image function inside the CKEditor.
2. You process the uploaded image server-side with a function you prepared or an external image processing API.
3. You return a JSON response with the object: `{image_url: ...absolute url to image...}`.

I have a similar implementation using TinyMCE so basically what I do in my case is I specify the URL for my upload and have a server-side function that receives the upload, moves the uploaded file to a specific folder and then proceeds to make a smaller, optimized version of the uploaded image and in the end I just return a JSON array with the image's absolute URL. What I do next is I just handle the response from my function in my TinyMCE initializer. I suppose it's similar for CKEditor.

My TinyMCE code example (irrelevant parts reduced with ...):

```js
tinymce.init({
    ...
    plugins: '...imagetools...',
    images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
        var xhr, formData;

        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
        xhr.open('POST', 'https://www.example.com/images/upload');

        xhr.onload = function() {
            var json;

            if (xhr.status != 200) {
                failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
                return;
            }

            json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
                failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
                return;
            }

            success(json.location);
        };

        formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());

        xhr.send(formData);
    }
});
```

So basically what this does is that it appends an image with that file location to the editor. I know it's not CKEditor, but the principle is the same. Hope it helps.

**EDIT FOR SPECIFIC DETAILS**

Just to clarify the insertion of the image inside TinyMCE.

The function that handles what is to be done once you insert an uploaded image to the TinyMCE instance is `images_upload_handler`. It is automatically triggered once you use the `imagetools` plugin. There are different options to handle it, you can [check here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/general-configuration-guide/upload-images/), but I am showing you my specific example which worked for my needs.

[image: Image Upload]

This is the icon you can use or you can also also the Insert -> Image menu.

[image: Image Upload Menu]

Once you use that function you get this dialog (the regular one has only the General tab available):

[image]

So once you upload an image, tinyMCE calls the `images_upload_handler` function and sends the information of the uploaded image via XHR.

You send the image file via POST to your URL function, it can be relative or absolute, I prefer absolute URLs in my case.

Then you get to this part of the code:

```
xhr.onload = function() {
    var json;

    // If your http response code is not 200 you get an error
    if (xhr.status != 200) {
        failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
        return;
    }

    // If not you receive a JSON response.
    // In my case the PHP response is:
    // echo json_encode(array('location' => site_url($path.'/'.$data['file_name'])));
    // $data['file_name'] is the original name of my uploaded file
    json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    // So the result of this is basically something like:
    // { location: "https://www.example.com/images/2020/06/theimage.jpg" }

    // Then what I check is if the location response is defined
    // and if it's a string
    // if not error
    if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
        failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
        return;
    }

    // If it is correct you indicate a successful upload and the next thing
    // TinyMCE does is go back to your upload dialog
    success(json.location);
};
```

Just that in this case your dialog now has this:

[image: Added new image]

Once you click on OK, TinyMCE inserts the image in the regular fashion it uses for image URLs and you can keep editing your content.

As for the PHP image upload/processing function that's up to you, you just need to return the location of the processed file to this handler.

Comment: Well, it's not really solved my problem. But I found It helped me a lot. Thank you for your example.

Comment: Well, can you please explain to me how you handle the response (get image_url value) and how you put the handled data into the tinymce in the example